# mysql not a good search engine

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, search-engine

I'm trying to create a search engine for our library. Currently I have table call book_tittle where the column contain:

```
id (int)
book_tittle (varchar 256)
book_description (varchar 256)
author_id
```

When someone search book title, for example he type: "big bird", I simply search from table where book_title like `'%big bird%'`.

If I have a book titled "big bird fly" this simple query was enough, but unfortunately when I have a book titled "big blue bird", the query will return nothing.

Can someone suggest me how to solve it? So that if someone search for "big bird", he will get "big bird fly" book and "big blue bird" book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify your field to a TEXT field instead of VARCHAR, you can use a FULLTEXT index. Then, you can use MATCH instead of LIKE to match a string. This match is much more flexible. You can match for `big bird` to match the words `big` and `bird` or you can match for `"big bird"` if you want to match the words together. You can also use wildcards, like `bir*` to match `bird` and `birth`.

Comment: can you tell me more about "match" ? any reference i can read ? and how text field can help me more ? will it become easier ?

Comment: You could start by Reading The Manual. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use a search engine. Check out [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html). It is available for PHP, .NET, Java etc.

Comment: thx for the answer. yes, i agree with you in one point. but the real problem is i also need to link the book tittle with author name. so, can search engine like lucene find "big bird" in tittle and author name like "matt%" for example ?

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your query like:

```
WHERE book_title LIKE '%big%' AND book_title LIKE '%bird%'
```

This can easly be done in your code. I don't know how large your book table is, a full-text index will probally be faster.

MySQL can also [implement](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1304) full-text, you will need to use the MyISAM engine. Lucene is more efficiënt tough.

Comment: if user enter many words, that would be difficult and slow right ? for example when user enter : "big bird fly together", then should i create WHERE book_title LIKE '%big%' AND book_title LIKE '%bird%' and book_title LIKE '%fly%'and book_title LIKE '%together%'
any other idea ?

Comment: Ari, that is correct. It isn't the most efficient method. But if u use an index on the book_title, it is acceptable. It depends on the size of your tabel. If it very large (hundred thousand records) I would look for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're right - relational databases don't make good search engines.

You need something like Lucene.  You'll have to ask it to index your data so you can do searching.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried MySQL's [built-in fulltext support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)?